# Right angle triangle only area given

Tags: triangles

A right angle triangle has area 6 cm square. Is it possible to find the perimeter of the triangle?

Comment: You can find the minimum value of the perimeter, unfortunately with the given information, the perimeter can be any value larger than that...  Where did you get the question?

Comment: No. The perimeter can range anywhere from $4\sqrt3+2\sqrt6$ to $+\infty$

Comment: My  daughter's Form Two (Grade 8) math question...

Comment: Then perhaps the (implicit?) intention is to have integer sides.  Then you have a unique solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't find it but you can know that it is greater than or equal to $\sqrt{24}$, if a,b,c (c hypotenuse) are the edges of the triangle, the area is equal to $\frac{ab}{2}$,so the perimeter equal to:

$$ a+b + \sqrt{(a+b)^2 - 2ab} = a+b+\sqrt{(a+b)^2 - 24}$$

so $a+b \geq \sqrt{24}$, and the perimeter $\geq \sqrt{24}$

Comment: In fact one can show that the perimeter is $\ge 2\sqrt3(2+\sqrt2) \approx 11.83 >$ twice your estimate.

Answer (score 0):

$$6=0.5ab$$
$$p=a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

these two equtions with three variables( impossible to find it)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's try.  Since $\frac{1}{2}bh=6$ then $bh=12$.  Let's try to use the information that also $b^2+h^2=c^2$ where $c$ is the length of the hypotenuse.  The thing we're looking for is $b+h+c$.  We know we can eliminate $c$ by $\sqrt{b+h}$ and we can eliminate $h$ with $12/b$.  So the perimeter has expression $b+12/b+\sqrt{b+12/b}$.

Looks like there's no way to actually find its number-value without knowing $b$, or at least one of the other edges.